# In the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{101}$ ,where discrete logarithms are $L_2(3)=69$ and $L_2(5)=24$. Compute the discrete logarithm $ L_2(60)$?

Tags: cryptography, discrete-logarithms

Now, I have that $L_2(60)=L_2(4*3*5)=L_2(4)+L_2(3)+L_2(5)=2+69+24=95$. 
So from my work $L_2(60)$ is $95$, but the answer on some other website gives $14$.
I just don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: This does not look like standard notation.  Perhaps some definitions would be a good idea.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  I am guessing that F101 means $\mathbb F_{101}$, the finite field with $101$ elements.  But I have no guess as to what $L_2(n)$ might mean.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the F, the L2(n) just describes the discrete logarithm.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  So you are saying that $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod {101}$ and you are asking to compute the minimal positive $a$ such that $2^a\equiv 60\pmod {101}$, yes?  (Note: please edit your post to reflect this, assuming I have it right.  Most people won't read through all the comments to discern your meaning.

Comment: I note, by the way, that $2^{14}\equiv 22\pmod {101}$.  $95$ is absolutely correct and your reasoning is sound.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thank you, I will edit it.

Comment: I can't imagine where the $14$ comes from. I expect some confusion (or just a good old fashioned error).

Answer (score 1):

Write $\equiv$ for "equal modulo $101$". You are told that $2^{69}\equiv 3$ and $2^{24}\equiv5$. Furthermore $2^2\equiv4$ trivially. From $60=3\cdot 5\cdot 4$ it then  follows that 
$$60\equiv2^{69}\cdot2^{24}\cdot2^2\equiv2^{95}\ .$$
This shows that in ${\mathbb F}_{101}$ one has $L_2(60)=95$, whereby  we have not checked that $2$ is actually a generator of the multiplicative group ${\mathbb F}_{101}^*$, vulgo: a *primitive root*.

Comment: I did check and it is a primitive root modulo $101$. I also check $2^{95} \equiv 60$ and $2^{14} \equiv 22$ so the OP's source was wrong.